# Mixing release dlls with debug main application exe

Tags: windows, visual-c++

Suppose I've one visual c++ application which is having a main executable and many dlls. I have 2 configuration release and debug.

I just want to know what will be possible effect of using mix, I mean using using debug dll with release main exe or debug exe with release dlls.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main potential problem would be that the DLLs won't be using the same runtime library as the executable.

That means that you can't share runtime objects such as file descriptors, and you can't allocate memory in one and release it in the other - although this won't be a problem if you follow best practice and always free memory from the same module it was allocated from.

There might also be an issue if you share non-POD (instances of a class, for example) between the DLLs and the executable.  I'm not sure whether or not class instances are guaranteed to be binary compatible between debug and release.

Comment: When you try to dup() a file descriptor allocated in the debug main app later in the release DLL you get an exception (invalid parameter). So be careful when mixing release and debug.

Comment: @MikeLischke: yes, any use of a file descriptor from the wrong instance of the runtime library is invalid.  Either it will be an unallocated descriptor, or it will be the descriptor for a different file object.  (There's nothing preventing the two runtime libraries from handing out numerically identical descriptors.)

Comment: What surprised me here was that I got an exception instead of just an error result, which is rather unusual for a low level runtime API, which can give you some extra trouble if you are only prepared to handle return values.

Comment: @MikeLischke: I agree it's surprising, in fact I don't quite see how that would happen.  I might have a look at the code for dup() on Monday.  I assume you mean a Windows exception rather than a C++ exception?  (Still, using a bad file descriptor is more or less analogous to using a bad pointer, so I guess terminating the process is a perfectly reasonable outcome.)