# Redirecting cout to stringstream from Debug build of DLL to Release build of EXE

Tags: c++, windows, dll, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have a DLL streaming text to `std::cerr`. The EXE linking (via `LoadLibrary()`) to that DLL needs to get the text being streamed.

I am using VS90.

I use the following class in the EXE for the redirection:

```
struct cerr_redirect {
cerr_redirect( std::streambuf * new_buffer ) 
    : old( std::cerr.rdbuf( new_buffer ) )
{ }

~cerr_redirect( ) {
    std::cerr.rdbuf( old );
}

private:
std::streambuf * old;
};
```

This works fine as long as both DLL and EXE are build using the same configuration (either both Debug or both Release). However, when running a Release built EXE with a Debug built DLL, the redirection does not work and none of the `cerr` output made in the DLL gets to the EXE.

**EDIT**

The Runtime Library is linked dynamically. The Debug built DLL links against "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" while the Release built EXE links against "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)".

I suspect this is the reason for this behavior; I believe `std::cerr` lives in the CRT. So when both DLL and EXE use the same CRT they share the same `std::cerr`, otherwise, they each have their own copy.

Could someone confirm if my understanding is correct?

If so, I think a solution to my problem is to define my own global stream in the EXE and let the DLL redirect `cerr` to it. Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: When you mix release and debug builds this means that the executable and the DLL use different runtimes.  And with two different runtimes, there are two different instances of `std::cerr`.

The simple way out of this bind is to stop mixing release and debug builds.

Comment: related: [Mixing release dlls with debug main application exe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12290565/33499) and [Linking against library in release and .exe in debug crashes in Visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1227653/33499)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Problem understood.